# Dynamic lines of an electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

We know that the dynamic lines of an electric field between two charge parallel planes are going like this:
[image: Dynamic Lines]

How are these lines if the opposite charge plates are like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

Comment: I read your answer but I have some issues about this. The dynamic lines in the case that the plates are non parallel will be more dense at the point that these are closer and less dense at the point wich these are remote? And in the third case...the dynamic lines are be exists only at the point that two plates are facing each other? I mean at the top of negative charge plate and the bottom of positive? And at this area the lines will be dense and uniform? Thanks

Comment: In the 2nd case, the field lines will be much denser where the plates are closer to each other. The lines will be sparse where the plates are father away.
In your 3rd case, There will be a very high surface charge density where the plates are closer to each other. Near the top in the (-) plate and bottom in the (+) plate.

Comment: There will be fringing effects near the ends and corners. The field lines will be perpendicular to the surface near the surfaces (some kind of a deformed **S**). Actual distribution requires you to do complicated calculations.

Comment: Yes... absolutely. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plates are arranged as shown, there will be non uniform charge density across the plates. The charge density will vary even at (*near*) the center.
The opposite charges on the plates will try to be as close as possible which will result in a non uniform charge distribution on both the plates.

In the idealized model we have uniform charge density on two **parallel** plates which are assumed to be much larger than their separation distance. That way the charge density will be very near to uniform near the center of the plates. The density will increase as you traverse outwards from the center.